# Facebook Plugin refuses to load on Website

Tags: jquery, html, css, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

Hi guys i'm trying to use a Facebook Plugin from the Facebook website. It's a simple comment plugin. It seems everytime i try to get this thing to load it refuses too. My page has a very slow loading time from this plugin, so i know it's trying to load something. What am i doing wrong with the directions from the website?

I'm posting the script right after the body tag as directed.

```
 <div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.3";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
```

and i'm placing the HTML inside of the Div i wish the plugin to load in. Which is also 300px in width.

```
<div class="fb-comments" data-href="http://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/comments/" data-width="300" data-numposts="3" data-colorscheme="light"></div>
```

But still this thing will not load.

Comment: Any error messages in console? Live example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I apologize it didn't even need the jQuery script: verbatim what i pasted into an page called fb.htm

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>

<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.3";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>

<p>FB tester</p>

<div class="fb-comments" data-href="http://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/comments/" data-numposts="5" data-colorscheme="light"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for that but sadly this does not fix the issue. I added the script to the bottom of my page to see if that would fix it. Sadly it's just making my page take about 10 seconds to load with still no Facebook plugin showing.